# How to remove multiple characters from a string?

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = "Sat Apr 27 2019 00:00:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

I have sample string saved to variable a. I want the output to be defined this way. The day (sat) part removed, and this (Apr 27 2019) part converted like this "27-4-2019". I'm new to programming and any help will be appreciated.

I've a time series kind of data and the code should match for the other samples taken at multiple intervals of time with the same format above as 'a'

Comment: Use `dateparser` Link: https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out [DateParser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), Have a look below example :

```
import dateparser 
a = "Sat Apr 27 2019 00:00:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
x = dateparser.parse(a) 
x.date().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

Output:

Parsed datetime object :

> datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 27, 0, 0, 14,tzinfo=StaticTzInfo
>   'UTC+05:30')

The extracted output will be:

> 27-04-2019

Comment: @shaikmoeed checkout answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer using the python standard datetime module, without using any other third-party module/library:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt_string = "Sat Apr 27 2019 00:00:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

dt = datetime.strptime(' '.join(dt_string.split(' ')[:6]), '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z%z')

print(dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

Output

```
'27-04-2019'
```

Answer (score 1):

The *"(India Standard Time)"* is not a standard form of the Time Zone. If it *"IST"* then *"%Z"* will be the directive of the datetime format code. Assuming your all data contains *"(India Standard Time)"*, then following is the code -

```
from datetime import datetime
a = "Sat Apr 27 2019 00:00:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
date_object = datetime.strptime(a, '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z (India Standard Time)')
new_date = date_object.strftime("%d-%-m-%Y")
```

Alternatively, if the string *'a'* contains different Time Zone name then following can be applied.

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

a = "Sat Apr 27 2019 00:00:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
a= re.sub(r'\([^()]*\)', '', a)
date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z ')
new_date = date_object.strftime("%d-%-m-%Y")
```

Comment: This will work only if there is (India Standard Time) at the end, on any custom timezone it will not work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In that case first, need to remove the string "(India Standard Time)" that above should apply. I am modifying this with this alternative.