# Regex to extract date and time from string

Tags: python, regex

What regex can I use to extract the date (dd/mm/yyyy) and time (hh:mm:ss) from a string in the form:

`Thu Jun 07 01:13:25 +0000 2018`

So that, given the above string, I retrieve:

`07/Jun/2018` and `01:13:25`

Comment: there no pattern such as `dd/mm/yy` in your given string, simple thing you should be doing is split the string upto 10th index in one part and from `11th index to 19th index` as 2nd part

Comment: You can look https://stackoverflow.com/a/56965132/4050015 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/56965680/4050015

Comment: Best thing is to use a date parser something like this https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: These don't  answer the question although I agree that using strptime is a better way of going about converting a string to a datetime object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use email utils to parse date and then convert in the format you wish:

```
from email import utils
date = utils.parsedate_to_datetime('Thu Jun 07 01:13:25 +0000 2018')

date.strftime('%d/%b/%Y')
date.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a complex regex, use the `datetime` module.

To parse the date (ref: [formatting codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)):

```
>>> s = 'Thu Jun 07 01:13:25 +0000 2018'
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.strptime(s,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 7, 1, 13, 25, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

To format a datetime object:

```
>>> d.strftime('%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S')
'07/Jun/2018 01:13:25'
```

You can also retrieve the individual date/time items, such as:

```
>>> d.year
2018
>>> d.month
6
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments and the other answer. The best general approach is to use the appropriate Python libraries, but to answer your question as it was asked.

```
import re
test = "Thu Jun 07 01:13:25 +0000 2018"

date_re = re.compile("^(?:Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat)\s+(?P<mon>(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\s+(?P<dd>\d{2})\s+(?P<hh>\d{2}):(?P<mm>\d{2}):(?P<ss>\d{2})\s+\+\d{4}\s+(?P<y>\d{4})\s*$")

tokens = date_re.match(test)
fields = tokens.groupdict()
print(f"{tokens['dd']}/{tokens['mon']}/{tokens['y']} {tokens['hh']}:{tokens['mm']}:{tokens['ss']}")

>>> 07/Jun/2018 01:13:25
```